# Can lee sin be grabbed during his Q jump kick?

Tags: league-of-legends

Say I use thresh/blitzcrank and I launch the hand (or throw the chain) to where Lee Sin is flying.

[image]

Will I be able to grab him in the middle of his "kick flight"?

Comment: with that angle the lee sin would have to be dumb enough to take q after seeing the hook coming heh which wouldn't be unheard of..

Comment: @Brian Actually, thresh can throw the hook in a different direction to the wind up. If thresh is facing lee when he starts throwing hook, but actually aims it as shown in the diagram, lee will probably try to jump to avoid the hook hitting him, only to get grabbed in the middle. BTW: +1 for the diagram ^.^

Comment: @Cruncher Thanks! I did it pretty fast so you could understand the idea in case my english explanation stink. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes he is targetable during the whole flight this means you could even stun him with an udyr autoattack if you are fast enough. A Blitzcrank/Thresh hook is obviously pretty hard to land on a flying Lee Sin but With a thresh E you can prevent him from dealing any damage  which is actually pretty easy to time with smartcast on. [Here you can see that it is possible with thresh E.](http://youtu.be/zLpUkf0LLuQ?t=3m)

You can interrupt most dashes with hard CC. The only exception to this are dashes which renders the Caster immune to CC (Vi R, Malphite R) or that make him untargetable (Maokai W, Master Yi Q)

Answer (score 2):

My guess is yes (though I haven't seen this happen before), since Lee Sin's Q and W are both dashes, not blinks. I've seen other dashes get interrupted (one example that sticks in my mind is when Daydreamin's Blitzcrank grabbed someone out of a Thresh lantern during an LCS game).

Comment: Yes he can be grabbed during this. Although from that angle you would have throw long before he uses the jump to get him.

Comment: It becomes more obvious when you realise that lee can safeguard mid-dash and never actually hit the target.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, he is able to. Blitzcrank is able to stop many different skills or travel trajectories with his Q and even he's E. I remember in a Pro game Daydreamin' grabbed ImaQTpie while he was traveling with Thresh's lantern the same would have happened if Lee was traveling with his Q.. ([Link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1tCbwAKiYPA))

Comment: In a thresh mirror at bot lane, the enemy thresh flayed my adc when he tried to lantern away and cancelled it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes he can, I have witnessed firsthand a Lee Sin die from a Blitzcrank mid Kick (Exactly how the diagram is in your example)